# Asymptotic Analysis for nested loop

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

I would like to understand Asymptotic Analysis better since I believe I don't have solid understanding on that. I would appreciate if someone can highlight a better approach to it. Here are two examples

`for (int i = 1; i <= n; i *= 2) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        count++;
    }
}`

This question is from Quiz and its answer is  O(n log n)

I watched a lecture of Stanford University and its example is below

```
for i = 1 to n
  for j = i + 1 to n
   if A[i] == A [j] return TRUE otherwise
   return FALSE
```

Asymptotic Analysis for second given problem is Quadratic O(n^2)

How can I know when is O(n log n) or O(n^2) they both have nested for loop?

Any answer is highly appreciated. Thanks beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first example is `O(nlogn)` because the outer loop repeats `log(n)` times, and each of its repeat require `O(n)` repeats of the inner loop - so this totals in `O(log(n) * n) = O(nlogn)`.

However, in the 2nd example - the outer loop requires `O(n)` iterations, and for each iteration `i` - it requires `O(n-i)` iterations of the inner loop. This means it will take `n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 2 + 1` total time. This is arithmetic progression, and the sum of it is in `O(n^2)`

There is no "easy way" to know the complexity without understanding some of what happens - complexity analysis is case dependent.

However, there are some hints that might help you, for example - if the iteration counter is multiplying each iteration - it is a strong indication a logarithm will be involved in the complexity function, like in your first example.